# Script that gets images wont show new images past 7 without a limit

Tags: php, html, image

I got a script that gets images from a folder and puts them inside a lightgallery. All is working fine, except when I add more than 7 images (or any new images for that matter). There are 7 images in the folder when I add 8.jpg it shows nothing, not in the gallery and not in the source code. What could be the cause of this?

My script:

```
<div id="lightgallery">
    <a href="<? echo $imagesmall; ?>">
        <img class="fullnieuwsimg" src="<? echo $imagesmall; ?>">
    </a>
     <?
        function scan_dir($dir) {
            $ignored = array('.', '..', '.svn', '.htaccess','index.html');

            $files = array();
            foreach (scandir($dir) as $file) {
                if (in_array($file, $ignored)) continue;
                $files[$file] = filemtime($dir . '/' . $file);
            }

            ksort($files,SORT_NATURAL);
            $files = array_keys($files);

            return ($files) ? $files : false; 
        }

        if(is_dir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/_intern/web/cms/images/Projecten/'.$contentcr[0]['alias'].'/') != FALSE){
            foreach(scan_dir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/_intern/web/cms/images/Projecten/'.$contentcr[0]['alias'].'/') as $entry) {
                $gallery .= '
                 <a href="/_intern/SNM/cms/images/Projecten/'.$contentcr[0]['alias'].'/'.$entry.'">
                      <img class="galleryimgs" title="'.$contentcr[0]['alias'].'" alt="'.$contentcr[0]['alias'].'" src="/_intern/web/cms/images/Projecten/'.$contentcr[0]['alias'].'/'.$entry.'" />
                 </a>';
            }
        }else{
            echo '';    
        }
        echo $gallery;
    ?>
</div>
```

The pictures are in the folder like this (barebone joomla cms) : [image]

All work, except 8.jpg or any other new images I add.

Comment: Can't fully wrap my head around it yet, but it seems to me all those `foreach()` loops make no sense at all.. Like there's one calling the function.. one inside the function that calls the function again.. ???

Comment: The function is only called once in the foreach. It just scans the folder of the current page alias and sorts them by natural order. All used to work, but now I can't add new images and I've got no idea why

Comment: Well so far I've learned that the function loop is completely pointless. Since you've added a dot to the `$ignored` array `$ignored = array('.'` this affectively means "*ignore all files that have an extension*". Also since you're overwriting the `$files` array after the loop in the function, putting the last modification times inside the array is completely pointless..

Comment: Some really weird stuff must be going on because from the code you've provided I can tell that the `scan_dir()` function will always return false unless there are files with no extension in the directory. So I'm amazed it's even returning a single image somehow..